Finding max value of a function
$$\frac{5-\cos(3x)}{3+\cos(5x)}$$
This is function whose max value I have to find.
My try
I tried differentiating, but I cannot find the values, plus I do not want to open $\cos(5x)$ as it turns too lengthy. Any hints would help a lot

$5-\cos 3x\leq 6,\  3+\cos 5x\geq 2.$ Therefore $\frac{5-\cos 3x}{3+\cos 5x}\leq 3.$ This bound $3$ is reached for $x=\pi.$

A cool answer!!

Since $-1 \leq \cos(3x) \leq 1$, the range of $5-\cos(3x)$ is $5-(-1)=6$ and $5-1=4$, $5 - \cos(3x) \in [4, 6]$
For $3+\cos(5x)$ we have $3+(-1)=2$ and $3+1=4$ so $3+\cos(5x) \in [2,4]$
To maximize $f(x)$, we want the maximum value of the numerator and maximum value of denominator.
The maximum only happens when $5-\cos(3x)=6$ and $3 + \cos(5x) = 2$
$f(x) = \frac 62 = 3$
Therefore, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $3$
Proof:
From range analysis $4 \leq 5 - \cos(3x) \leq 6$ and $2 \leq 3 + \cos(5x) \leq 4$
Consequently the function is bounded by $\frac 44 \leq f(x) \leq \frac 62$
which simplifies to $1 \leq f(x) \leq 3$
For $f(x)$ to reach 3 we would need $5-\cos(3x)=6$ and $3+\cos(5x)=2$ this happens if $\cos(3x)=-1$ and $\cos(5x) = -1$ which are possible simultaneously for certain values of x.
$\cos (3x) = -1$ implies $3x = (2k+1)\pi$ for integers $k$
$\cos(5x) = -1$ implies $5x=(2m+1)\pi$ for integers $m$
these two equations can be satisfied simultaneously when $x=(2n+1)\pi$ for integers $n$

How do you know that the maxima for the numerator and the minima for the denominator are attained at the same value of $x$? At least provide such a value for $x$

And I think it should be $3+\cos(5x)=2$ instead of $=5$

Somewhat alternative approach:
To try to maximize the function, you can try to simultaneously maximize the numerator and minimize the denominator.  Since the range of the cosine function is $~[-1,1]~$ the obvious try is to attempt to find a value of $~x~$ such that
$$[ ~- \cos(3x) ~] = 1 ~~~~\text{and simultaneously} ~~~~[ ~ \cos(5x) ~] = -1, \tag1 $$
if feasible.
Note
The fact that $~3~$ and $~5~$ are relatively prime integers will automatically imply that it is feasible to find a satisfying value of $~x.~$  This will be discussed later in this answer.
The above (very simplistic) approach only works if the constraint in (1) above can be satisfied.  If it can't be satisfied, then a different approach is needed.

Since $~\cos(\theta) = -1 \iff \theta~$ has form $~\pi(1 + 2n) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z},$ 
you are trying to find at least one value of $~x~$ such that :

$3x~$ has form $~\pi(1 + 2m) ~: ~m \in \Bbb{Z} \iff $ 
$\displaystyle \frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{1 + 2m}{3}.$

$5x~$ has form $~\pi(1 + 2n) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z}\iff $ 
$\displaystyle \frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{1 + 2n}{5}.$


So, the entire problem has been reduced to finding integers $~m~$ and $~n,~$ such that
$$\frac{1 + 2m}{3} = \frac{1 + 2n}{5} \iff (5 + 10m) = (3 + 6n) \iff $$
$$2 + 10m = 6n \iff 1 + 5m = 3n. \tag2 $$
Note
A diophantine equation like $~A = Bm + Cn~$ is always solvable whenever $~B,C~$ are relatively prime.  Therefore, the equation in (2) above must be solvable in integers $~m,n.$  See the Addendum for a proof of this.
One of the satisfying answers to the equation in (2) above is $~(m,n) = (1,2).$
So, you can set the value of $~x~$ such that
$$\frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{1 + 2m}{3} = 1 \implies x = \pi.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
To Prove:
Given integer constants $~A,B,C,~$ such that $~B,C~$ are relatively prime, the diophantine equation
$$A = Bm + Cn$$
must be solvable.
Proof:
Without loss of generality, you can assume that $~C > 0.~$
That is, $~A = Bm + Cn \iff A = Bm + [-C](-n).$
Further, $~C = 1~$ yields the solution $~m = 0, ~n = A.$
Therefore, without loss of generality, you can assume that $~C > 1.~$
Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,C-1\}.$
Let $~T~$ denote the set
$$T = \{ ~(B \times 0), ~(B \times 1), ~(B \times 2), ~\cdots, (B \times [C - 1]) ~\}.$$
For each element $~t \in T~$ there must exist a unique element $~s \in S~$ such that $~t \equiv s \pmod{C}.~$
In other words, when you divide $~t~$ by $~C,~$ the remainder must be an element in $~S.$
For each $~t \in T,~$ let $~f(t)~$ denote the unique element in $~S~$ such that $~t \equiv s \pmod{C}.$

Is it possible that there exists two distinct elements $~t_1, t_2 \in T~$ such that $~f(t_1) = f(t_2) ~?$
Suppose that this is possible.
Then, there exist two integers $~i,j~$ such that
$$0 \leq i < j \leq C-1 ~~~~\text{and} 
~~~~(B \times i) \equiv (B \times j) \pmod{C} \implies $$
$$C ~| ~[ ~B \times (j - i) ~].$$
Since $~B,C~$ are assumed relatively prime, this implies that $~C ~| ~(j - i).$
However, this is impossible, because it has been assumed that $~0 \leq i < j \leq C-1 \implies 1 \leq (j-i) \leq C-1.$

Therefore, it is impossible for two distinct elements $~t_1, ~t_2 \in T,~$ to be such that $~f(t_1) = f(t_2).~$
Therefore, the set
$$\{f(B \times 0), ~f(B \times 1), ~f(B \times 2), ~\cdots, f(B \times [C - 1]) ~\}$$
must exactly coincide with the set $~S.~$
Therefore, there must exist exactly one element $~t \in T,~$ such that $~f(t) = 1.$
Therefore, there must exist exactly one integer $~i,~$ such that $~0 \leq i \leq C-1,~$ and such that $~(B \times i) \equiv 1 \pmod{C}.$
This implies that $~C ~| ~[ ~(B \times i) - 1~].$
This implies that there exists an integer $~k~$ such that
$$(C \times k) = (B \times i) - 1.$$
Therefore,
$$1 = (B \times i) + (C \times [-k]).$$
Therefore,
$$A = (B \times i \times A) + (C \times [-k] \times A).$$
Therefore, one solution of the diophantine equation
$$A = Bm + Cn$$
is given by
$$m = (i \times A), ~~~~n = ([-k] \times A).$$
